# error code 0x8007057 windows cannot install required files

Tags: windows-7

When I start the installation proccess on my laptop it shows me the error code 0x80070570 with the message saying Windows cannot install required files. Please I really need help I was trying to fix this about 9 hours and still did not find any solution.

Comment: What are you trying to install? Windows 7 itself?

Comment: Yes Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this link](https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-windows-cannot-install-required-files-0x80070570/)

Fix Windows Cannot Install Required Files 0x80070570

Method 1: Update BIOS

Method 2: Change the SATA operation to AHCI

Method 3: Check the installation media is not damaged

Method 4: Run System File Checker (SFC) and Check Disk (CHKDSK)

Method 5: Run MemTest86+

Method 6: Using Microsoft Management Console

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Can't change SATA to AHCI because there is no option in bios, installation is not damaged in fact I tried it now on the other pc and I've already did CHKDSK. I will try methods 1, 5 and 6

Comment: Man, try something because I think I'm spaming links, because I just waist and carrying this around my self. It's a good way to spend my time searching around the web, and found only this for the best. Try research 0x80070570 fix, in the google, or duckduckgo.com

Comment: No, sry but I just told you I absolutely appreciate your help and effort to write this comment. Thank you for your help, but as you can see I fixed this issue.

Comment: You are welcome, be well and have a nice time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my problem was just my USB. I was using obviously shitty **ADATA UV100** and then switched to **TDK TF10** that I was using in the past time just for installing OS. Thank you for your help guys. I never thought that the problem can be my USB until now. I still don't know why it was not working but for the past few installations it was working..??